# Django search functionality

Tags: python, html, django, web

I added a search functionality to my website, such that if you goto www.mywebsite.com/search/texthere , it displays all the songs with title=texthere. I would like to add this functionality to my index page.

In my page, there is an input box where users could type the input and the press submit to submit the input but it goes to some another page.
How can I solve this?

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^search/(?P<query>[\w\-]+)/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="/search/">
     <input type="text"  name="query" value="me"><br>
     <input type = "submit">
</form>
```

What I want is when the user clicks submit button, the text from the input box should be used as the query in **urls.py**  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Your current search url needs query value also to be passed. But in form action only `/search/` is there. During the form submission query value will be passed in request.POST and you wont be able to pass the the query value directly in the url like this `/search/sample_query`

You need to add one more **url**:

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
```

And in **views**:

```
def search(request, query_via_url=false):
    # if form submission is true
    if request.post:
        query_via_form = request.post.get('query', '')
        ...

    # if query value is passed directly via url
    if query_via_url:
        ....
```

Comment: I didn't understand this, can you please explain it a bit more?Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get this work by using `redirect`.

1. Add a url for `/search/` endpoint in your form:

   ```
   url(r'^search/$', views.search_redirect),
   ```
2. In the `views`:

   ```
   def search_redirect(request):
       query = request.POST.get('query', '')
       return redirect('/search/{}/'.format(query))
   ```
3. the form in your `index.html` should use method 'POST':

   ```
   <form action="/search/" method="POST">
     <input type="text" name="query" value="me"><br>
     <input type = "submit">
   </form>
   ```

When you submit the query string, `search_redirect` function get the `query` string and redirects the request to your `/search/<query>/` function.

Hope this will help.